# Last instruction in a program (Computer architecture)

Tags: assembly, logic, hardware, cpu-architecture

What happens after the last instruction  is executed in a program ? 
Let's assume that I have a 16 bytes ram and a single program is fitting in that space.

The PC holds the address of the current instruction to be fetched, so at the last instruction, do we have something like a STOP instruction? What  does this STOP instruction  actually do and how it is implemented with hardware logic? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In embedded systems where there is no such thing as an operating system (OS), the program simply never terminates. You *have* to provide an infinite loop somewhere, and your program only terminates whenever the power is turned off.

If you have a program lying in RAM and you forget to make an infinite loop, then the behaviour is *undefined*. The CPU will try to execute garbage that is in the RAM past your program and will either crash, or execute garbage until it's program counter rolls back to another meaningful area of the address space and execute another subroutine (or even the same program again if the program counter counted through the entire address space).

(What I said does not applies to microcontroller that have a sleep mode, but back in the 80s no CPU had sleep modes and systems with no OS (or only a very trivial one) were common)

Answer (score 2):

Most programs are started by other programs (for example, part of the OS), so that their last instructions either return control to their caller or send a signal that they are finished.

The STOP instruction stops the computer (as in shutting it down); only the operating system should be allowed to execute such an instruction.  In fact, it may be that the attempt by something outside the OS to execute such an instruction is that "signal" I referred to earlier.

Comment: what if there is no OS?

Comment: Then that program effectively *is* the OS.